# How to autoload 'libraries' in laravel 4?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I've created a library folder in app folder to add my app libraries. I've updated app config file and composer.json to autoload that folder, but when I run the command `composer dump-autoload` I get the next error:

> `{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'App\\Libraries\\Search\\SearchServiceProvider' not found","file":"D:\\Users\\Miguel Borges\\Documents\\Trabalhos\\Tese\\portal\\bootstrap\\compiled.php","line":4130}}PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\Libraries\Search\SearchServiceProvider' not found in D:\Users\Miguel Borges\Documents\Trabalhos\Tese\portal\bootstrap\compiled.php on line 4130
>       [Finished in 1.1s with exit code 255]`

**My app folder tree:**

```
app
| ...
+ libraries
| + search
| | - Search.php
| | - SearchFacade.php
| | - SearchServiceProvider.php
| + lib2
| | - ...
| + lib3
| | - ...
| | - Theme.php
| - ...
- filters.php
- routes.php
```

**SearchServiceProvider.php**

```
namespace App\Libraries\Search;

use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class SearchServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider {

    /**
     * Register the service provider.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app['search'] = $this->app->share(function($app)
        {
            return new Search;
        });
    }

}
```

**composer.json**

```
    "autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/libraries",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php"
        ]
        // ,
  //       "psr-0": {
  //           "app": "app/libraries"
  //       }
    },
```

Basically, I need to autoload all the libraries within the 'libraries' folder.

Comment: You could just add a line: `"app/libraries"` to the classmap section?

Comment: not, the folders in classmap, only load the files in the root, not in subfolders.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should create a top-level namespace for your application.

Then put all libraries *you* code under that namespace. **Note:** Any third-party libraries should (hopefully) be installed via Composer and therefore have its own namespace/autoloading setup.

Your directory structure would then be:

```
libraries
    Myapp
        Search (note directory is capitalized)
            Search.php
            SearchFacade.php
            SearchServiceProvider.php
        AnotherLib
```

Then your classes will follow that namespace:

File: `Myapp/Search/Search.php`:

```
<?php namespace Myapp\Search;

class Search { ... }
```

And finally, your autoloading setup:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/libraries",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ]
    ,
    "psr-0": {
         "Myapp": "app/libraries"
    }
},
```

Comment: thx for your reply. this way works, but I think the file structure is a bit redundant. there is no other way to do autoloading?

Comment: While it feels redundant at first, as you build out more functionality it really helps keep things clean and organized in my experience.

Comment: How does this work with controllers?  For example, I have an API with namespace Kitties/Api10; in my controllers.  Would I do libraries/Kitties/Api10/PoniesLibrary.php and in PoniesLibrary use namespace Kitties/Api10?

Comment: That gets into the grey area of "opinion". You can certainly do that. I don't usually put controllers in the application library (and thus none are within a namespace), but that's just my style. It looks like you have the correct idea for namespaces and how they relate to file locations. For controllers, if in a namespace, you'll need to move them into your application library.

Comment: Capitalization is important folks