# How to include some file inside a laravel controller

Tags: php, laravel

I have a file that calculates something, lets say tax. `Tax.php`, this is inside some folder, lets say `/MyCalculations/Taxes/Tax.php`.

Now I want this file to be accessible inside my controller, How do I access this file, or how do I access those calculations inside this file?

Sample code of Tax.php:

```
<?php namespace MyCalculations/Taxes;

  class Taxes extends Enginge {
    //some calculations here
  }
?>
```

I'm using laravel. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could start by creating a namespace for your application, and place a folder in your app directory, perhaps app/Projectname.
Then you could place your calculations namespace there there. Then autoload everything in your project by adding

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "..."
    ],
    "psr-0": {
        "Projectname": "app/"
    }
},
```

to your composer.json file and then do a dump-autoload. Then you could use dependency injection in your controller, like so:

```
use Projectname\MyCalculations\Taxes\Tax;

class TaxController extends BaseController {

    protected $tax;

    public function __construct(Tax $tax)
    {
        $this->tax = $tax;
    }

    public function getTaxValue()
    {
        $value = Input::get('value');

        return $this->tax->getAwesome($value);
    }
```

Comment: @nielisano Sir, if I'm using blade to display those calculations, can also put `use Projectname\MyCalculations\Taxes\Tax;` inside the myview.blade.php and access those data or i should do it via controller?

Comment: You could make a facade for that, so you could do Tax::getAwesome($value), but i'd much rather do that in a presenter before passing the variable to a view. Check out https://github.com/ShawnMcCool/laravel-auto-presenter and read about facades in the Laravel Docs.

Answer (score 0):

Edit your composer.json file and add the 'files' section to it to it:

```
"autoload": {
    ...

    "files": [
        "app/MyCalculations/Taxes/Tax.php"
    ]
},
```

Then you just have to execute:

```
composer dump-autoload
```

And use them everywhere.

If you are on PHP 5.5, you also can use traits:

```
<?php namespace MyCalculations/Taxes;

  trait TaxesTraits  {

     function calculateX()
     {

     }

  }

  class Taxes extends Enginge {
     use TaxesTraits;

     public function calculate()
     {
        $x = $this->calculateX();
     }
  }
```

Comment: @Belmark Caday : If you plan to have multiple custom classes I would recommend setting up a global namespace and a new `libraries` directory for your custom classes. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17593618/845680) is a good post to read on the subject - I have used similar structures in the past and have been pleased with the results.