# Where I am going wrong the the code?

Tags: php, laravel-4

Controller class-

```
<?php
class PageController extends BaseController {
    public function home ()
    {
      $var = Testrundetail::getAll();
      return View::make('hello')->with('name', $var);
    }

    public function about ()
    {
      return View::make('about');
    }

}
```

Model class-

```
class Testrundetail extends Eloquent {
    protected $table = 'testrundetail'

    public function getAll ()
    {
      $getAll = Testrundetail::all();
      return $getAll;
    }
}
```

routes

```
Route::get('/', 'PageController@home');
Route::get('/about', 'PageController@about');
```

hello.blade.php

```
<!doctype html>

<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1> Hello, {{ $var }} </h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

i am getting the error -

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException
Class 'Testrundetail' not found

1. Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException
…\app\controllers\PageController.php7
```

What is wrong with the code ?? :(

Comment: Is your Testrundetail model autoloaded?

Comment: Where did you store Testrundetail.php ? in `app/models/` directory?

Comment: @WebNovice yes testrundetail.php is in app/model directory

Comment: @SergioAristizábal autoloaded as in? i am a newbie here .. pls tell with lil explanation

Comment: @SergioAristizábal something like this ??

`code`http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading

`code`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584810/how-to-autoload-libraries-in-laravel-4

??

Comment: Look in `app/autoload.php`. Also, are you using namespaces?

Comment: No i ma not using namespaces..!!

Comment: Rename your `testrundetail.php` to `Testrundetail.php` and check. Make it as the same case as your class name.

Comment: WebNovice : I tired but still getting the same error :(

Comment: WebNovice : btw there is one more wired thing about the class.. this model class is not showing those particular color for keywords and all.. in my editor full code is in black only..

Comment: hey  .. now i am getting the error

Non-static method Testrundetail::getAll() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: use public static function getall() instead of public function getall().!! Well yes it was namespace problem , hope you would have solved it!!

Comment: Creator - I have a very different thing to ask. I need your suggestion ,

Im totally new to php and here i am asked to develop a tool.. I tired using laravel4 framework but learning the framework itself taking so long .. 
can I develop my web-based tool with using a framework by just writing simple php and html script .. I mean would there be a problem in binding all the scripts and putting them in the server and things like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class is not found the first thing to check is whether it just hasn't been autoloaded.

To autoload files in your composer.json you need to add the directory your class is in (if it hasn't already been added) to this section:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
    ],
}
```

Once you have confirmed the folder is in your composer.json, assuming you are using composer, you need to run this command in your websites root directory.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Put a `;` after this line

```
protected $table = 'testrundetail'
```

as

```
protected $table = 'testrundetail';
```