# Permission denied after composer dump for Laravel "helper" directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, composer-php

I have created a directory in my app folder called helpers and created a new file with a helper function.

I ran composer dump which completed successfully.

Now when I try to go to any page in my app I get:

```
Warning: require(C:\wamp\www\abc\app\helpers): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\wamp\www\abc\vendor\composer\autoload_real.php on line 58
```

I have read a few posts about how to fix this for Linux but I'm using windows 7. All permissions are set correctly so I'm a bit lost.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to include this folder in composer.json  like this

```
"autoload": {
        "classmap": [
            "app/commands",
            "app/controllers",
            "app/models",
            "app/database/migrations",
            "app/database/seeds",
            "app/tests/TestCase.php",
            "app/helpers"
        ]
    },
```

and then fire `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: Not "files": ["app/helpers"] ?

Comment: for you files works, but please check other answers and articles on this http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584810/how-to-autoload-libraries-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by specifically naming the file I wanted to use:

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": [
        "app/commands",
        "app/controllers",
        "app/models",
        "app/database/migrations",
        "app/database/seeds",
        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
    ],
            "files": [
                "app/helpers/general.php"
            ]
},
```