# laravel 5 Library for load CSS, JavaScript

Tags: php, laravel

I want to include CSS and Javascript with the help of Laravel 5 helper. But I don't know which is there.

```
href="{{ url() }}/assets/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"
```

I need to load with the helper of laravel. Not to traditional.

Please any suggestion tell me.

Answer (score 1):

In Laravel you can use the provided `HTML` class for including the `CSS` and `JS` in a project

**Stylesheet:**

```
{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}
```

**Javascript:**

```
{{ HTML::script('js/your_js_file.js') }}
```

**NOTE:**

You can also use `URL` class

**JS**

`{{ URL::asset('js/your_js_file.js'); }}`

**STYLE**

```
{{ URL::asset('css/style.css'); }}
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using **LARAVEL 5** find the solution here **http://laravel.io/forum/09-20-2014-html-form-class-not-found-in-laravel-5**

Comment: But any helper class for that .i want to helper class.I  am learning laravel 5

Comment: look at the url provided for your help if you are using laravel 5

Comment: But i want to load within one array all my css file name and js also

Comment: For that you have to autoload libraries, checkout this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17584810/how-to-autoload-libraries-in-laravel-4

Answer (score 0):

One way is using : `URL::asset('css/file.css');`

For using `{{ HTML::style('css/style.css') }}`, you will have to go through following steps:

Add the following lines in the require section of composer.json file and run composer update "illuminate/html": "5.*".

Register the service provider in config/app.php by adding the following value into the providers array:

'Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider'

Register facades by adding these two lines in the aliases array:

'Form'=> 'Illuminate\Html\FormFacade',

'HTML'=> 'Illuminate\Html\HtmlFacade'

Comment: But i want to load within one array all my css file name and js also